# How to sum up values between 2 dates in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007

Lets say I would like to sum up values from January to March. Below is an example

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╗
║ Column A  ║ Column B   ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╣
║ 1/30/2011 ║ 1          ║
║ 1/25/2011 ║ 1          ║
║ 3/30/2011 ║ 1          ║
║ 3/25/2011 ║ 1          ║
║ 5/13/2011 ║ 1          ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╝
```

I did some research and found I can use the SUMIFS function

> =SUMIFS(B1:B5,A1:A5,">="&DATE(YEAR(2011),MONTH(1),DAY(1)),A1:A5,"<="&DATE(YEAR(2011),MONTH(4),DAY(1)))

But for some reason instead of returning 4 it returns 0. I would really appreciate if someone could figure out why.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Year/Month/Day do what you're expecting, see:

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/year.php

They return the year value, month value, and day value of their argument. Try entering

```
=YEAR(2011)
```

and compare it to

```
=YEAR("1/30/2011")
```

That said, you can get what you want by just putting the dates in the quotes

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B5,A1:A5,">=2011-01-01",A1:A5,"<=2011-04-01")
```

produces 4 in my Excel.

Comment: you are correct, I had the Year/dates functions wrong. Your example is the answer and it helped me out greatly. Thank you. I still needed to create a generic spreadsheet for the current year so I went with this function.   =SUMIFS(B1:B5,A1:A5,">="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1),A1:A5,"<="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),4,31))